# Tibco Administrator to Mobile Web App

Tags: web-applications, mobile-website, administrator, tibco

Does anyone know if the TIBCO Administrator have API/Webservice/Rest API?. I'm planning to integrate tibco administrator features to a mobile web application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no API (or at least no public API), however there are several sh scripts from which can be achieved the same actions as in GUI - such as appdeploy (deploy, undeploy, export configuration (Global Variables only)), check on running apps (it's only ping from hawk anyway) etc